# Delay works fine; slight revision and no delay--why?

Tags: android, runnable, android-handler

This code, contained in `QuizFragment.java`, delays for `ms` milliseconds and then executes `loadNextFlag`. Works fine. (`ms` = 2000 milliseconds)

```
public void pauseAndThenShowNextFlag(long ms){
    showTimer("pauseAndThenShowNextFlag");
    pauseTimer(); // 7/17/15--DAS
    handler.postDelayed
            (
                    new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            loadNextFlag();
                        }
                    }, ms       // ms-second delay
            );
    startTimer();
}
```

I changed the delay to be in another object, so then the above became:

```
public void pauseAndThenShowNextFlag(long ms){
    showTimer("pauseAndThenShowNextFlag");
    Timer.xhaltTimer4(ms);
    loadNextFlag();
    startTimer();
}
```

Here's `xhaltTimer4` in `Timer.java`:

```
public static void xhaltTimer4(long ms){
    customHandler.postDelayed
            (
                    new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            pauseTimer();
                        }
                    }, ms); // 2000 milliseconds for 2-second delay
}
```

Absolutely no delay occurs. Is it because `loadNextFlag` contains a lot more code than `pauseTimer`? Why does that make a difference? Where is the line drawn in terms of how much the `Runnable` `run` method must do to enable the delay?

I tried this revised `xhaltTimer4`--still no delay:

```
public static void xhaltTimer4(long ms){
    Handler h = new Handler();
    h.postDelayed
            (
                    new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            pauseTimer();
                        }
                    }, ms); // ms-millisecond delay
}
```

Here's `pauseTimer`:

```
public static void pauseTimer(){
    timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
    customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
}
```

Here's `loadNextFlag`:

```
public void loadNextFlag() {
    startTimer();
    String timerDisplayString;
    oneImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    showTimer("loadNextFlag");
    currentTimeSpent = timeStringToMillis(Timer.getTimerString());// was prevTimeSpent--7/17/15--DAS
    InputStream stream ;
    // get file name of the next flag and remove it from the list
    consecutiveWrong = 0;

    String nextImage = quizFlagPathList.remove(0);
    correctAnswer = nextImage; // update the correct answer
    answerImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    ableButtons(true);

    // display current question number--2nd and 3rd parameters are INPUT into the xml statement
    questionNumberTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.question,
            (correctAnswers + 1),
            FLAGS_IN_QUIZ));
    // extract the region from the next image's name
    String region = nextImage.substring(0, nextImage.indexOf('-'));

    // use AssetManager to load next image from assets folder
    AssetManager assets = getActivity().getAssets();

    try{
        stream = assets.open(region + "/" + nextImage + ".png");

        Drawable flag = Drawable.createFromStream(stream, nextImage);
        flagImageView.setImageDrawable(flag);
    }catch (IOException exception){Log.w(TAG, "Error loading " + nextImage, exception);}

    Collections.shuffle(flagPathList); // shuffle file names

    // put the correct answer at the end of flagPathList
    int correct = flagPathList.indexOf(correctAnswer);

    flagPathList.add(flagPathList.remove(correct));

    int k = 0;
    countriesToUse.clear();
    for(int row = 0; row < guessRows; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < guessLinearLayouts[row].getChildCount(); col++)
            countriesToUse.add(getCountryName(flagPathList.get(k++)));

    countriesToUse.set(countriesToUse.size() - 1, getCountryName(flagPathList.get(flagPathList.size() - 1)));

    if(MainActivity.getAlphabetize()) Collections.sort   (countriesToUse);
    else                              Collections.shuffle(countriesToUse);

    k = 0;
    // add 3, 6, or 9 guess Buttons based on the value of guessRows
    for (int row = 0; row < guessRows; row++) {
        // place Buttons in currentTableRow
        for (int column = 0; column < guessLinearLayouts[row].getChildCount(); column++) {
            // get reference to Button to configure
            Button newGuessButton = (Button) guessLinearLayouts[row].getChildAt(column);
            newGuessButton.setEnabled(true);
            // get country name and set it as newGuessButton's text
            String fileName = countriesToUse.get(k++);
            newGuessButton.setText((fileName));
        }
    }
} // end method loadNextFlag
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because **xhaltTimer4** is synchronous method call, it won't wait for **ms**. Inside this you are posting one Runnable,which will run after some delay. You should try to move `loadNextFlag()` inside `run()` method of runnable like this

```
public static void xhaltTimer4(long ms){
    Handler h = new Handler();
    h.postDelayed
            (
                    new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            pauseTimer();
                            loadNextFlag()
                        }
                    }, ms); // ms-millisecond delay
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I would like to, but it's not a static method and can't be made so. I'd like to pass `loadNextFlag` as a parameter somehow and use it here, but I doubt that's even possible. I guess I could move `xhaltTimer4` to the class where the call is made...

Comment: Why I'm asking is that I'm having trouble implementing a working `Timer` class that I found/stole/modified. My thinking was that the `QuizFragment` class contains a `Handler` that causes the delay specified before the next flag is shown but my `Timer` class has its own `Handler` to keep track of time spent by user on current flag. I thought reducing to one `Handler` would maybe fix the problem. I think I should drop this question and fix what the actual problem is in that code and maybe ask a different question.

Comment: Sorry.. but i didn't get what you are trying to acheive. May be specific question will help